# Diferencia entre una serie de fechas almacenadas en una base datos y guardarlas en cada iteración

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un situación que no puedo resolver, por lo que recurro a ustedes si me pueden ayudar.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de prestamos de libros para una pequeña biblioteca, guardo los datos del libro prestado en una base de datos con los siguientes datos:

[image: tabla de préstamos de libros]

Lo que quisiera es que cuando se cumpla la fecha tope (fechaTope), el sistema comience a guardar los días de atraso en el campo "diasAtraso", eventualmente calculando la diferencia de días entre la fecha actual en su momento y fecha tope (fechaTope). El objetivo es que con esos días de atraso yo pueda calcular los días de sanción al usuario sin pedir libros.

Actualmente tengo el siguiente AJAX:

```
function obtenerDatos() {
$.ajax({
  url: "modulos/atrasos.php",
  method: "POST",
  success: function (datos) {
    console.log(datos);
  },
});
} 
obtenerDatos();
```

Mi Archivo PHP:

```
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM prestamos");
$stmt->execute();
$prestamos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($prestamos as $prestamo) {

$fecha1 = new DateTime($hoy); 
$fecha2 = new DateTime($prestamo['fechaTope']);
$estado = 1;

if ($fecha1 > $fecha2) {

    $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) retrasos FROM prestamos WHERE estado = :estado");
    $sentencia->bindParam('estado', $estado);
    $sentencia->execute();
    $registros = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $retrasos = $registros['retrasos'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $retrasos; $i++) {

        $diferencia = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
        $diasAtraso = $diferencia->days;
        $query = "UPDATE prestamos SET diasAtraso=:diasAtraso WHERE fechaTope < :hoy AND estado = :estado";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam('diasAtraso', $diasAtraso);
        $stmt->bindParam('hoy', $hoy);
        $stmt->bindParam('estado', $estado);
        $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco cada ayuda a mi problema.

Comment: Y el error que te da cuál es ?

Comment: Me actualiza un solo número para todos los registros.

Comment: @MarcosEsp como yo lo veo, tu implementación tiene varios problemas. Actualmente busca todos los prestamos. ¿Que pasaría cuando tengas miles de registros? ¿No sería correcto buscar solo aquellos cuya `estado = 1 AND fechaTope >= DATE(NOW())`? ¿Para que necesitas saber cuantos `$retrasos`? Díra que ese código es inecesario. Cuando actualizas el campo `diasAtraso` ¿no deberías actualizar solo el `idPedido` que estas analizando?

Comment: La respuesta va en el campo respuesta, completa. mira [answer]

Comment: Puedes hacer el calculo en el mismo SQL: `UPDATE prestamos SET diasAtraso = datediff(current_date,fechaTope) WHERE fechaTope < current_date AND estado = 1`.

Comment: efectivamente yo recomiendo usar el sql para lograr eso, incluso puedes usar la misma funcion en el `select *,datediff(current_date,fechaTope) as dias from prestamos WHERE fechaTope < current_date AND estado = 1` asi podras mostrar los dias de atrazo sin la necesidad de actualizarla en la base pues se generaria cada ves que lo consultas